# laravel + vuejs + vue-route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

есть компонент,подскажите как решить вопрос, если я перешел по ссылке route-link и потом обновил страницу в браузере, то меня перекидывает на главную страницу сайта

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <header class="fixed">
            <div class="box-header">
                <a href="" class="logo"></a>
                <div class="header-right">
                    <ul class="nav-header">
                        <li><router-link to="/webshop"><font-awesome-icon icon="home" /> Домой</router-link></li>
                        <li><router-link to="/shop"><font-awesome-icon icon="store" /> Склад</router-link></li>
                        <li><router-link to="/webshop"><font-awesome-icon icon="shopping-cart" /> Корзина</router-link></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="user-header">
                        <ul class="top-user nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <div class="user-box">
                                        <div class="avatar_user v-btn v-btn--icon v-btn--large">
                                            <img src="https://wpimg.wallstcn.com/f778738c-e4f8-4870-b634-56703b4acafe.gif" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user-name">
                                            <span>Aslero</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app'
    }
</script>
```

файд app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './shopRoute'
import Shop from './components/layouts/Shop.vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faShoppingCart,faHome,faStore,faArrowRight,faArrowLeft,faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faShoppingCart,faHome,faStore,faArrowRight,faArrowLeft,faTimes)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
})


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    components: { Shop },
    template: '<Shop/>'
})
```

файл роутинга

```
import Index from './components/pages/shop/Index'
import Shop from './components/pages/shop/Shop'
const routes = [
    {path: '/webshop', component: Index},
    {path: '/shop', component: Shop}
]

export default routes
```

Comment: Это по большей части зависит от того, как вы в контроллере обрабатываете.

Comment: я на данный момент скомпилировал через npm run dev и просто вывел страницы, по ссылкам если перехожу срабатывает vue-router но при обновлении страницы редирект на главную

Comment: может сталкивался кто с такой проблемой?